# Where should I place my sqlite database for proper packaging?

Tags: application-development, quickly, sqlite

I built my first application with quickly uses a sqlite database file. It contains all the settings of the program. While developing I simply put it into the root folder of the app.

```
quickly package
```

Did complain about the place, so I first removed it into the media folder. Then quickly could finish packaging.

As expected, after installation, the settings database landed in `/usr/share/app/media` folder.

Thats not a good place for this I would say. I'd rather see this in `/etc/app/` for example. And if I would do so, would it break the rules of the App Showdown?

So where should I place it in my development environment. Maybe I can place the whole structure in the debian folder?

Answer (score 1):

If the database stores user-settings, it should go into `~/.config/<app>/`.  If you want to ship a copy with the default settings, that should go into /opt/ with your other files, and get copied into `~/.config/<app>/` the first time the user runs your app.

`/etc/` should only be used for storing system-wide settings, not user settings or defaults.

Comment: Thanks for answering :-) Well, in my case it's not that kind of user settings. The database contains information for generating AppArmor profiles. I'm not quite sure If this should be stored in home-folders. If I follow your advice, where exactly do I have to place the default database inside my quickly development environment, that it will land in /opt/ after packaging and installing?

Comment: Hello, just wanted to say thank you. The variatn with creating the db in .config worked :-)